# NewsAPI Exclude Sources or Websites

Tags: java, android, feed

Trying to curate a news feed using [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/) on an Android app, using Java. Is it possible to exclude sources/blogs from the response? I could parse the results and skip the sources I don't want but I'm currently returning 50 responses and of the 50, more than half are from these sources, so I wouldn't be left with much.

Any other way to do this?

Comment: This question is either off-topic or mis-tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything

You can use the `excludeDomains` parameter to exclude sources you don't want returned.